# URL Filtering with squid and HTTPS website

Tags: https, filtering, squid

I'm looking for the easiest way to block websites on my squid proxy. I've considered squidguard, but I'd prefer to have it as simple as possible to block/unblock very few websites according to the time of the day.

I have created an ACL containing the URL to block, with the lines

```
acl bad_url dstdomain "/etc/squid/bad_url.squid"
http_access deny bad_url
```

I remove those lines from crontab using a sed command, and it works as planned.
However accessing the site through HTTPS still works.

Any solution within Squid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what you have already:

```
acl bad_url dstdomain "/etc/squid/bad_url.squid"
http_access deny bad_url
```

add the following information

> http_access deny CONNECT bad_url

your final configuration will look something like this;

```
acl bad_url dstdomain "/etc/squid/bad_url.squid"
http_access deny bad_url
http_access deny CONNECT bad_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have configured Squid to intercept HTTPS traffic.  Typically, intercepting HTTPS traffic is not recommended, as it is simulating the "man-in-the-middle" attack.